# Android - How do I specify the external storage path string inside xml

Tags: android, xml, android-external-storage

I'm creating a custom preference for which I want to specify the default value for download location.

```
<com.example.DownloaderPref
    android:key="download_path"
    android:defaultValue="/storage/emulated/0/downloads"
    android:title="Download Path" />
```

The problem is that not all devices emulates external storage to `/storage/emulated/0` so it will not work on all devices.

I'm finding the equivalent of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for xml so that I could use it in the path as a prefix.

Is there anything in android which could help me with this.

Comment: Since this is your own custom preference, why do you need to set the value in XML? Set the value in your `DownloaderPref` class.

Comment: @CommonsWare because I'll be creating a lib project for this preference which can be used in other projects with some customizations. So I don't want to hardcode the value in java class

Comment: There's nothing that you can do in preference XML to dynamically generate a path, though. So, you will need to offer a setter on `DownloaderPref` for providing the value.